# npm install is building .cmd files in my angular project root directory

Tags: node.js, angular, command-line-interface, angular-cli

I have a project that I've been working with for quite some time and it has built and compiled (and still does on a different machine) for months. Now, when I run the command npm install it runs as normal, but at the end of the process, it builds out tons of .cmd files (and another accompanying file) in the root folder of my project.

when I run ng serve i get the error: 
Unknown browser query `basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")`

I'm completely stumped as to how to get my project back to a usable and buildable state. Have never had problems with my angular builds like this. Also my package.json file is below.

```
{
  "name": "project",
"version": "0.0.0",
"license": "MIT",
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve",
"build": "ng build",
"test": "ng test",
"lint": "ng lint",
"e2e": "ng e2e"
},
 "private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@angular/cli": "1.0.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/animations": "^4.0.1",
"@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
"angular2-notifications": "^0.7.4",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"pdfmake": "^0.1.28",
"rxjs": "^5.1.0",
"zone.js": "^0.8.4"
 },
"devDependencies": {
"@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
"@types/node": "~6.0.60",
"codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
"jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
"karma": "~1.4.1",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
"karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
"protractor": "~5.1.0",
"ts-node": "~2.0.0",
"tslint": "~4.5.0",
"typescript": "~2.2.0"
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue, using windows 10

Answer (score 0):

I face the same issue after changing my laptop domain and create a new user profile.

These files should be generated under `node_modules/.bin` folder.

As a workaround, you can delete these files manually after each time you run `npm install` then run `ng serve` you should not see errors.

Another information from [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24122)

> It looks like the contents of your `node_modules/.bin/` folder are
>   entirely pushed to your root folder. It might have to do with
>   something installed on your computer, a config of `npm` or an antivirus.

Comment: you answer is working fine. other issue I think it's related.when installing a package it's not added to package.json