# Why command "npm-install" installs files in the root folder

Tags: angular, npm, frontend, npm-install, package.json

I pull my front-end project from repository, without `node_modules` folder.
I use to `npm install` to install all dependencies as declared in `package.json`.
But also I get those files installed  in the root folder:

[image]

here is package.json file:

[image]

When I try to run the project by `ng serve` command I get this error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: ...\Projects\byuer_app_v2 contains both .browserslistrc and browserslist
See "...\Local\Temp\ng-DnzJEb\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

I think the error caused by the files installed in the root folder.

So my question is why those files installed? And how can I prevent to install it?

Comment: Have you created this project using the cli command ng new ... ?

Comment: @JacopoSciampi I don't know, this project was created by another developer

Answer (score 0):

Hope these references help

[npm install is building .cmd files in my angular project root directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44187207/npm-install-is-building-cmd-files-in-my-angular-project-root-directory)

[Many unnecessary files generated by 'npm install' in root directory of app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48036339/many-unnecessary-files-generated-by-npm-install-in-root-directory-of-app)

Basically they said that maybe something is wrong with node setup or windows settings.